# SelectionChanged for ListView inside HubSection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I get this error when i click any of the item on listview.
System.NullReferenceException - {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

My MainPage.xaml Hub code

```
<Hub x:Name="MainHub" Header="My Hub">
<HubSection x:Name="Test" Header="Online" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,30,0,0">
<DataTemplate>
<ListView Name="ItemData1"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="Catergory_Click">
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
 </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListView>
 </DataTemplate>
 </HubSection>
 </Hub>
```

I have 3 ListView with same SelectionChanged function

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

 private void Catergory_Click(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        RootObject obj = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as RootObject;
        User.Setting.AddOrUpdateValue("SectionName", obj.name);

    }
```

Same code works fine without the Hub control and Section.

Comment: Do you sure that you have `RootObject` type in your `SelectedItem` value? because, I don't see how you setup `ItemsSource` property to your `ListView`

Comment: @AndriiKrupka I don't have ItemSource property for ListView..
I had to use Test.DataContext = TestSection; to display data in ListView inside HubSection.

    List<string> TestSection = new List<string>();
    var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < objResponse1.LongCount(); i++)
    {
     TestSection.Add(objResponse1[i].name);
    }
    Test.DataContext = TestSection;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed SelectionChanged to ItemClick..Works fine now

```
 <Hub x:Name="MainHub" Header="My Hub" Foreground="White">       
<HubSection x:Name="Test" Header="Online" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,30,0,0">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListView x:Name="TestListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemClick="TestListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"  Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

```
private void TestListView_ItemClickobject sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject obj = e.ClickedItem as RootObject;
        User.Setting.AddOrUpdateValue("CourseSectionName", obj.name); 
    }
```